# Issue with python memory management

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have some trouble explaining a memory footprint phenomenon I am seeing with some code that I wrote.
The code basically looks like this:

```py
import datetime as dt
import psutil
import gc
from my_package import some_function
process = psutil.Process()
start_date = dt.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0)
end_date = dt.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 18)
while start_date <= end_date:
    for hr in range(0,22,3):
        a = some_function(dt.datetime(start_date.year,start_date.month,start_date.day,hr))
    print(
        f"\n"
        f""
        f"Date processed: {start_date:%Y-%m-%d}\n"
        f"Memory consumption:\n"
        f"Resident memory (MB): {process.memory_info().rss / 1024**2}\n"
        f"Virtual memory (MB): {process.memory_info().vms / 1024**2}\n"
        f"Object count: {len(gc.get_objects())}"
    )
    gc.collect()
    start_date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

`some_function` initializes some objects and makes a call to the file system extracting a lot of filenames and returns a set of custom objects built from the retrieved filenames. Simplified it looks like this:

```py
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.args = args
    @staticmethod
    def from_str(some_str):
        # do some stuff with some_str
        return SomeClass(arg1_derived_from_str,arg2_derived_from_str)
def some_function(timestamp:dt.datetime)->set[SomeClass]:
    timestamp_path = _derive_path(timestamp)
    filename_strings = {f.name for f in timestamp_path.glob("*")}
    return {SomeClass.from_str(fname) for fname in filename_strings}
```

When I run this code the object count remains constant through all iterations except the first two or so. The virtual memory however increases by 2MB after about half of the iterations are done. Since I had troubles with memory leaks in the package `my_package`, I am inspecting this very thoroughly.
What is striking is that when I replace the call to `some_function` by some filesystem call like `pathlib.Path(f"/some/path/{start_date:%y/%m/%d}/{hr}").glob("*")` the memory footprint shows a constant signature like I would expect given the unchanging object count.
So this leaves me wondering whether the call to `some_function` introduces some memory leak that will pile up if I increase the number of iterations or whether the small increase I am observing is completely normal?

Comment: Can you show what `some_function` does?

Comment: It sounds to me like there are some circular object references. These don't get collected during reference-counting GC, so it waits for full GC to clean them up. As a result, memory grows during the first few iterations.

Comment: Yeah, if the behavior is clearly caused by `some_function,`, then it seems pretty silly to NOT show us that function...

Comment: I have tried to include some details on how `some_function` works, but it is very involved with my local filesystem layout so rather hard to present it in a concise way.

Comment: @Barmar but then why am I not seeing the object count increase parallel to the increase in memory footprint?

Comment: `gc.get_objects()` only counts reachable objects.

Comment: Meaning there can be objects that keep each other alive through circular references without me seeing them in gc.get_objects() because they are not reachable from any object in my accessible namespace?

Comment: I'm not really clear about the problem you're describing. Does it keep increasing by 2MB during every iteration?

Comment: Nope, just a one-off jump after maybe half the iterations. When I try it on another date range the jump happens too, but already after 20% of the iterations are done. When I increase the range of processed dates I can observe more then one jump, but they are not evenly spaced.

Comment: could it just be that `filename_strings = {f.name for f in timestamp_path.glob("*")}` produces more paths for some timestamps than others?

Comment: @Anentropic I will investigate this once more, I had loosely looked into this and excluded it in the beginning.

Comment: @Anentropic Unfortunately it is really not the easy solution like this. It is also that when the memory footprint jumps upwards it will remain at the elevated level. So I will have a time series that is essentially a stair function, constant for periods of time with upward jumps in between. So something seems to be accumulating in memory, but I cannot figure out what or why.

Comment: But well, since I cannot go into much detail on the inner workings of some_function both due to its complexity as well as it is company code it seems pointless to take this further here. Thanks everybody for the suggestions.

Comment: I think I found the problem.
In the SomeClass.from_str function defined in my question above I had a nested dataclass that I used to organize the deconstruction of filenames into arguments for the SomeClass object initialization. I moved the definition of this dataclass outside of the SomeClass.from_str function (to the top-level of the module in which SomeClass is defined, to be exact) and now the memory footprint in all my tests is constant over the complete loop and the functionality remains.
Will post more detailed answer with code example in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
I apologize for the rather convoluted formulation of the question and the incomplete code snippet. It was my lack of understanding and the complexity of the code in `SomeClass` that made it hard for me to get to the point. I have now produced a rather small working example that illustrates what went wrong in my code. So my implementation of `SomeClass` had a nested dataclass defined like below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import gc
import psutil

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(some_str):
        return SomeClass(*SomeClass.disassemble(some_str).to_tuple())

    @staticmethod
    def disassemble(some_str):
        @dataclass
        class StringAttributes:
            attr1: str

            def to_tuple(self):
                return (v for v in self.__dict__.values())
        return StringAttributes(some_str[0])


def some_function(strings: set[str]) -> set[SomeClass]:
    return {SomeClass.from_str(s) for s in strings}
```

When I now call `some_function` in a loop (the code snippet below is just in the same module as the code snippet above) and monitor the memory usage using psutil I observe that the virtual memory increases ever so slightly at irregular intervals (on my machine it happens once when counter reaches 1550 and another time when counter reaches 27650). The count of objects tracked by the garbage collector however stays constant from the second iteration onwards.

```py
counter = 0
process = psutil.Process()
while True:
    a = some_function({str(counter)})
    print(
        f"\n"
        f""
        f"Date processed: {counter}\n"
        f"Memory consumption:\n"
        f"Resident memory (MB): {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}\n"
        f"Virtual memory (MB): {process.memory_info().vms / 1024 ** 2}\n"
        f"Object count: {len(gc.get_objects())}"
    )
    gc.collect()
    counter += 1
```

When I move the definition of the dataclass outside of the definition of `disassemble`, then the virtual memory signature remains constant throughout the whole loop as far as I have tested it.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import gc
import psutil

@dataclass
class StringAttributes:
    attr1: str

    def to_tuple(self):
        return (v for v in self.__dict__.values())  #


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(some_str):
        return SomeClass(*SomeClass.disassemble(some_str).to_tuple())

    @staticmethod
    def disassemble(some_str):
        return StringAttributes(some_str[0])


def some_function(strings: set[str]) -> set[SomeClass]:
    return {SomeClass.from_str(s) for s in strings}
```

Moving the dataclass definition outside of the `disassemble` definition thus solves my problem, but two questions still remain for me:

- Why does this solve my problem, i.e. what exactly is staying in the process' memory when I define the dataclass in a nested way? I guess the problem is that I return an instance of the dataclass from the `disassemble` method and thus move it outside of the scope where it is defined.
- Why does the increase in virtual memory not reflect in the length of the list of objects tracked by the garbage collector or in the list of unreachable objects (`gc.garbage`)?

I put the refined question here [Nested dataclass introducing memory leak, but gc.get_objects() has constant length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76951466/nested-dataclass-introducing-memory-leak-but-gc-get-objects-has-constant-leng)

Comment: not sure about why the memory leak, but it's a better design to define the dataclass once outside of the method instead of redefining it every time the method is called